# Entity Framework Binding to a Query with a .Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Ok I am trying to do

```
from s in _db.Students.Include("Advisor") orderby s.LastName select s;
```

once I get that working there will be several more Includes, but I need to figure this out first. Basically I have no idea how to bind text boxes to the included advisor information. My bindings for the main student data work, but not for the advisor. The bindings look like:

```
Text="{Binding Path=Advisor.AcadAdv}"
```

Also the Main grid contains the DataContext to my CollectionView of students objects.

Advisor is a table with an id a foreign key to student and 5 text fields with names of the advisors in them.

Comment: You sample binding looks correct, can you show one of your working bindings?

Comment: Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" That binds the student's first name to the text box.

Comment: Any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: So I assume your Student class has an `Advisor` property, which is an instance of the `Advisor` class.  Is that correct?  Also, like @Dennis said, check for binding errors in the output window.  You might check Tools->Options->Debugging->Output Window to make sure they are turned on (in VS).

Comment: Yes this is the error I get for each text box. System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'AcadAdv' property not found on 'object' ''EntityCollection`1' (HashCode=18479254)'. BindingExpression:Path=Advisor.AcadAdv; DataItem='ListCollectionView' (HashCode=36798147); target element is 'WatermarkTextBox' (Name='txtAcadAdv'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Comment: Yes student has a property Advisor, but when I tested creating it and accessed the Advisor property the intellisense didn't show any of the table fields listed.

Comment: I'm going to assume my problem is that Advisor is an EntityCollection. I have no idea how to bind to that then.

Comment: @tyler.reid Is the `Advisor` property of your `Student` class a collection of some sort?  Is this EF Code First or an EDMX?

Comment: @CodingGorilla it is from an edmx file. All these classes were generated from my db schema.

Comment: Is the Student -> Advisor a one-to-many relationship? (Which would imply a collection of some sort).

Comment: @CodingGorilla no it is a one-to-one relationship thats why I assumed it was a scalar, but it created it as a collection.

Comment: Can you look at the actual `Student` class that is generated and tell when the type the `Advisor` is?

Comment: EntityCollection<Advisor>, it actually returns ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<Advisor>("StudentDataModel.FK_student_advisor", "Advisor");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to details you provided, you can:
1) specify item in the binding path (something like this: {Binding Path=Advisor[0].AcadAdv})
2) bind Advisor property to any ItemsControl
3) make a view model, which will have Advisor property as a first item of collection
4) make Advisor a scalar property, not a collection (this will require entity model changes).

Comment: How would I make it a scalar when I try to change it to a one-to-one relationship I get an error that it must be *.

Comment: @tyler.reid what is your requirement? does a student need only one adviser or more than one?

Comment: A student will only have one advisor record in the table. Everything in my database is a one-to-one except for like 4 tables and 2 are a one-to-many and the other 2 are many-to-many.

Comment: @tyler.reid, show tables definition (which Students and Advisor maps to) and their foreign keys.

Comment: @tyler.reid this blog post by 'Benny Michielsen' will help you with defining the one-to-one mapping in EF. http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2011/06/02/entity-framework-4-1-one-to-one-mapping/

Comment: Thanks for all the help I ended up changing the Database schema and using the foreign key to student as the primary key in the 1-to-1 tables because I didn't model it correctly the first time. After doing that my issue was solved.